# 2004 Malibu not starting

Tags: starting, ignition, malibu

I have a 2004 Chevy Malibu.  having starting problem; it turns over and act like it is starting, then dies after a few seconds.  Have noticed that it started before,but when i put  it in drive it died  put back in park and it did start,  and seemed to run fine.  Now it is not starting. dash lights not comeing on either.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few possible culprits from your description. Just to cover all the bases:

- test your battery voltage, it needs to be above 12.6V for a healthy battery, above 11.8V to start a car. Since you've been having trouble, give the battery a boost before testing
- have your ignition switch tested, it may not be making good electrical contact
- test your fuel pressure (may indicate an obstructed fuel filter or bad fuel pump)
- have your idle air control valve looked at, it may not operate properly. One way to bypass this problem is holding the accelerator down when turning the ignition
- have your mass airflow sensor looked at, it may have become defective

These are the common things to first look at with a car having trouble starting, or dying after starting.